coherent sheaves annihilated by ideal sheaves and morphisms between them
Let $X$ be a Noetherian scheme and $\mathcal I\subseteq \mathcal O_X$ be a coherent ideal sheaf defining a closed subscheme $Z$ of $X$. Let $i:Z\to X$ be the closed immersion. I have the following question: If $\mathcal F,\mathcal G$ are coherent $\mathcal O_X$-modules such that $\mathcal I \mathcal F=\mathcal I \mathcal G=0$, then is $i^*\mathcal F\cong \mathcal F$ and $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal O_X}(\mathcal F,\mathcal G)\cong \text{Hom}_{\mathcal O_Z}(i^*\mathcal F,i^*\mathcal G)$ ?
If true, this should be standard, but I was unable to locate it in Hartshorne. Of course, this is true when $X$ is affine, which is my motivation.

the condition $\mathcal{IF}=0$ implies that $\mathcal{F}$ is supported on $Z$. Tensoring $0 \to \mathcal{I} \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_Z \to 0$ by $\mathcal{F}$ gives an isomorphism $\mathcal{F} \to i^*\mathcal{F}$

$ i^* \mathcal{F} $ is a sheaf on $ Z $ whereas $ \mathcal{F} $ is a sheaf on $ X $ so the statement $ i^* \mathcal{F} \cong \mathcal{F} $ that you write is false (although I understand what you want to say). The correct isomorphism is $ i_* i^* \mathcal{F} \cong \mathcal{F} $ which comes from stalkwise isomorphisms of the natural map $ \mathcal{F} \rightarrow i_* i^* \mathcal{F} $
The second statement is correct and it comes from adjunction and the isomorphism in the previous paragraph $ \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_Z} (i^* \mathcal{F}, i^* \mathcal{G}) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X} (\mathcal{F}, i_* i^* \mathcal{G}) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X} (\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})  $

Thanks a lot... could you tell me why something like the comment by @usr0192 may not work?

Did you read the first line in my answer? Also, that comment has the right idea of tensoring but arrives at the same wrong statement as yours.

Yes, I understood that ... I have a related question then ... if $M\in D^b(\mod R)$ and $I\subseteq J$ are ideals, then since each $M_i/JM_i$ is naturally in $\mod(R/I)$, so we can view $M/JM$ to be in $D^b(\mod R/I)$ ... now what would be a sheaf version of this? If $\mathcal F \in D^b(coh X)$ and $\mathcal I \subseteq \mathcal J$ are coherent ideal sheaves, can we view $\mathcal F/\mathcal J\mathcal F$ naturally as a member of $D^b(coh Z)$, where $Z$ is the closed subscheme defined by $\mathcal I$? (All my schemes are Noetherian...)

Ask a different question.
